# iOS11 Safari: Add to Home-screen localstorage lifecycle

Tags: ios, safari, local-storage, ios11, iphone-standalone-web-app

I found Home-Screen app localstorage is not deleted by Safari clear cache.
It seems to be persistent storage, but I cannot find any documents about this.

My Question is

1. Is there any document about this behavior?
2. Home-Screen app localstorage lifecycle. when will be cleared? how to clear?
3. Can I use localstorage to save persistent token for PWA?

There is localstorage tester [here](https://wilfrem.github.io/add_to_homescreen_test/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage is not cache, it is persistent storage. You can add or delete values manually.

Apple's documentation says the following:

> Safari supports the latest HTML5 offline data storage features. Your
>   application can store its information on the local machine using
>   either a simple key/value-based data store, or a robust SQL database.
>   The data is stored locally and persists across launches of Safari so
>   your application doesn’t need a network connection to access the data,
>   improving startup time and overall performance.

This storage is limited to 5 MB and *can* be cleared if the device is running low on space, but this is the main way to store data on the user's device.

You can learn more about local storage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: This answer helps explain local storage in general but, the question is asked particularly about storage in home screen apps (PWA's). Is this shared with Safari? Is it documented?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Does localStorage (and cookies) 'survive' the process of being added to homescreen, like it does on Chrome/Android?

Comment: From my experiments and discussions with an Apple engineer, I find that no storage is shared between the app running in-browser and from-homescreen, not even localStorage.

Comment: I can confirm @MaxWaterman 's comment, I have multiple PWAs in production and this is quite a pain, especially for apps that require authentication.